# Getting QGIS SLD From OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, qgis-plugins, sld

QGIS has a plugin called OpenLayers. From that plugin, we can get a very pretty map. I have downloaded some shapefiles for the region (a city in my case) I am targeting.

When I put the shapefiles on top of the OSM map, everything looks perfect (playing a little bit with transparency...)

- Now I would like to cut the OSM map area not contained in my polygon shapefile while still keeping all the OSM attributes (names, roads, colors etc...) and keeping the zoom-able ability of the OSM map.
- **THEN** I'd like to export the result as a SLD. I'll use that into GeoServer.

How would I go and do that or is there another way for doing that?

Comment: Is it just the style you want, or are you trying to get data as well?

Comment: @nmtoken Omg. you are so late on this one. I asked the question on May the 16th 2016. I don't even know how to operate QGIs anymore. Long story short, I remember using for that project GeoServer. SLD, and all the other files where hosted on Geoserver and I thinks I got them from openstreetmap. Brief, the project succeeded (class assignment passed ;-))